# $\mathbb{F}$-subalgebra generated by a set

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Assume that $A$ is an $\mathbb{F}$-algebra, where by $\mathbb{F}$ I just denote an arbitrary field. Furthermore, if $X \subset A$ is a proper subset, how do we define the $\mathbb{F}$-subalgebra of $A$ generated by $X$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the smallest subalgebra of $A$ containing $X$, that is, the intersection of all subalgebras containing $X$.

It can also be seen as the $\mathbb{F}$-subspace of $A$ generated by all products of elements of $X$.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I was looking for a synactic description. Like for instance, how does one element look like?

Comment: For instance, if $X = \{ x \}$ is a singleton, you just get polynomial expression in $x$.

Comment: If $X = \{ x_{1}, x_{2} \}$, you get elements like $a_{1}x_{1} + a_{2}x_{2} + a_{11}x_{1}^{2} + a_{12} x_{1} x_{2} + a_{21} x_{2} x_{1} + a_{22} x_{2}^{2} + \dots$.

Comment: So for instance given a finite subset $X=\{x_1,x_2,...,x_n \}$ an element of the subalgebra generated by $X$ is like a polynomial in the above variables?

Comment: *Non-commutative* polynomial *expressions*. As to the latter, the representation need not be unique.

Comment: The above sum is formal? Or can be an infinite series?

Comment: A finite sum only.